# How can I use Goo.gl as my URL shortener in Twitter for iPhone (Tweetie)?

Tags: twitter, iphone, url-shortening, goo.gl

I've gone to *Settings* → *Services* → *URL Shortening* → *Custom*. What do I enter as the "URL shortening endpoint"?

Comment: I'm not seeing any requests coming into my server from Tweetie when I use a custom URL.  It would appear it's broken, or the docs are wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment you can't as there is no official API available.

An extract [from this post here](http://googlesocialweb.blogspot.ca/2010/09/google-url-shortener-gets-website.html):

> Even without an official API, there
>   are extensions  available for browsers
>   like Chrome (eg: goo.gl URL Shortener,
>   Shareaholic for Google Chrome) and
>   Firefox (eg: goo.gl lite). Before 
>   people start writing code to
>   incorporate our new features, we
>   wanted  to let you know we do plan to
>   release an official API for goo.gl in 
>   the future. You’ll be able to use the
>   API to shorten URLs, expand  URLs, and
>   view analytics from directly within
>   your own applications

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but here is a PHP class that uses an unofficial Goo.gl API: http://code.basvd.nl/google_url_shortener_1.0/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how flexible Tweetie is, you might be able to use this:

http://ggl-shortener.appspot.com/?url=%@

Technical details here: http://ggl-shortener.appspot.com/instructions/